# How to make App Resolution compatible with all deivces

Tags: node.js, react-native

### **I am getting some issues with Resolution(Which is not compatible with all devices)**

***The Resolution is compatible with all device,***

1. Not Correct
2. Not Correct
3. Correct

The Resolution should be same like 3th device

[image]

**This is the link for Code :-**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UrtEgLkEGGvpTdw7Zq4mUW_l_HQNBvDPkDeeWANWGKc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It'll be very difficult for someone to help without seeing your code, can you post it? What's the difference between #1 and #3?

Comment: Check with the link for Code

Comment: I repload that. Thank you for reminding me

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here instead of giving a link. This is because code on other sites can change over time. See this [FAQ for more detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/17493431)

Comment: Actually the code is to long not coming in the edits